# Derived Class Deserialization

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, derived-class

I have a problem with deserialization with my logic simulation program. 

Here are my element classes:

```
public class AndGateData : TwoInputGateData
{

}

public class TwoInputGateData : GateData
{
    public TwoInputGateData()
    {
        Input2 = new InputData();
        Input1 = new InputData();
    }
    public InputData Input1 { get; set; }
    public InputData Input2 { get; set; }
}

public class GateData : ElementData
{
    public GateData()
    {
        OutputData = new OutputData();
    }

    public OutputData OutputData { get; set; }
}

public class ElementData
{
    public int Delay { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

And here are classes responsible for sockets:

```
public class InputData : SocketData
{

}

public class SocketData
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public SignalData SignalData { get; set; }
}
```

SignalData is not important here. So, I won't write it (in order to keep this question clean) here unless somebody says it is necessary.

CircuitData is very important:

```
[XmlRoot("Circuit")]
public class CircuitData
{
    [XmlElement(typeof(AndGateData))]
    [XmlElement(typeof(OrGateData))]
    public List<ElementData> elements = new List<ElementData>();
    public List<WireData> wires = new List<WireData>();
    public void AddElement(ElementData element)
    {
        elements.Add(element);
    }
    public void AddWire(WireData wire)
    {
        wires.Add(wire);
    }
}
```

Wires are not important right now. 

Now, I have written some Serialization:

```
public class CircuitDataWriter
{
     public static void Write(object obj, string fileName)
     {
         var xmlFormat = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CircuitData));
         using(Stream fStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None) )
         {
             xmlFormat.Serialize(fStream,obj);
         }
         Console.WriteLine("Circuit saved in XML format.");
     }

}
```

It works just like I wanted, it produces that xml document:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<Circuit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> 
-<AndGateData> 
<Delay>10</Delay> 
<Id>bfee6dd7-5946-4b7b-9d0b-15d5cf60e2bf</Id> 
-<OutputData> <Id>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</Id> </OutputData> 
-<Input1> <Id>7c767caf-79a9-4c94-9e39-5c38ec946d1a</Id> <SignalData xsi:type="SignalDataOn"/> </Input1> 
-<Input2> <Id>d2cad8f8-8528-4db3-9534-9baadb6a2a14</Id> <SignalData xsi:type="SignalDataOff"/> </Input2> 
</AndGateData> 
<wires/> 
</Circuit>
```

**But I have problem with my DESERIALIZATION. Here is the code:**

```
public static CircuitData Read()
{
    var reader = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CircuitData));
    StreamReader file = new StreamReader("Circuit.xml");
    var returnCircuitData = new CircuitData();
    returnCircuitData = (CircuitData) reader.Deserialize(file);
    return returnCircuitData;
}
```

Now, it deserializes my `Circuit.xml` to object, but this object only contains `Id` and `Delay`, it does not contain `Input1`, `Input2` or `Output`. So, it is treated like `Element`, not like `AndGate`. I tried to solve it out for a day but it seems that no one has that kind of problem.

Comment: Try adding a parameterless constructor to `InputData`.  Will it deserialize then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a suggestion for you, make the `Write` method generic like this and create the serializer using `objectToSerialize.GetType()`:

```
public static void Write<T>(T objectToSerialize, string fileName)
{
    var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(objectToSerialize.GetType());
    ...
}
```

The [`XmlSerializer.Deserialize()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsh84875.aspx) method returns object, you can make your `Read` method generic like this:

```
public static T Read<T>(string fileName)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(fileName))
    {
        return (T)serializer.Deserialize(file);
    }
}
```

Other than that you might want to read about:

- [XmlInclude](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute.aspx) that is used when you serialize derived classes.
- [XmlArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmlarray.aspx) and [XmlArrayItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayitemattribute.aspx) that are used for controlling serialization of arrays